# issue with longtable starting at the top (second caption appears first)

Tags: captions, longtable

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-6]

a

b

c 

d

e

f

g


\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!6}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\caption{\label{tab:unnamed-chunk-1}My table}\\
\hiderowcolors
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{My table \textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
\endhead
\showrowcolors
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108.0 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258.0 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215 & 19.44 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360.0 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440 & 17.02 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\addlinespace
Valiant & 18.1 & 6 & 225.0 & 105 & 2.76 & 3.460 & 20.22 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Duster 360 & 14.3 & 8 & 360.0 & 245 & 3.21 & 3.570 & 15.84 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Merc 240D & 24.4 & 4 & 146.7 & 62 & 3.69 & 3.190 & 20.00 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
Merc 230 & 22.8 & 4 & 140.8 & 95 & 3.92 & 3.150 & 22.90 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
Merc 280 & 19.2 & 6 & 167.6 & 123 & 3.92 & 3.440 & 18.30 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 4\\
\addlinespace
Merc 280C & 17.8 & 6 & 167.6 & 123 & 3.92 & 3.440 & 18.90 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 4\\
Merc 450SE & 16.4 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 4.070 & 17.40 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Merc 450SL & 17.3 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 3.730 & 17.60 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Merc 450SLC & 15.2 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 3.780 & 18.00 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Cadillac Fleetwood & 10.4 & 8 & 472.0 & 205 & 2.93 & 5.250 & 17.98 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
\addlinespace
Lincoln Continental & 10.4 & 8 & 460.0 & 215 & 3.00 & 5.424 & 17.82 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Chrysler Imperial & 14.7 & 8 & 440.0 & 230 & 3.23 & 5.345 & 17.42 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Fiat 128 & 32.4 & 4 & 78.7 & 66 & 4.08 & 2.200 & 19.47 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Honda Civic & 30.4 & 4 & 75.7 & 52 & 4.93 & 1.615 & 18.52 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
Toyota Corolla & 33.9 & 4 & 71.1 & 65 & 4.22 & 1.835 & 19.90 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
\addlinespace
Toyota Corona & 21.5 & 4 & 120.1 & 97 & 3.70 & 2.465 & 20.01 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Dodge Challenger & 15.5 & 8 & 318.0 & 150 & 2.76 & 3.520 & 16.87 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
AMC Javelin & 15.2 & 8 & 304.0 & 150 & 3.15 & 3.435 & 17.30 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
Camaro Z28 & 13.3 & 8 & 350.0 & 245 & 3.73 & 3.840 & 15.41 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Pontiac Firebird & 19.2 & 8 & 400.0 & 175 & 3.08 & 3.845 & 17.05 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\addlinespace
Fiat X1-9 & 27.3 & 4 & 79.0 & 66 & 4.08 & 1.935 & 18.90 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Porsche 914-2 & 26.0 & 4 & 120.3 & 91 & 4.43 & 2.140 & 16.70 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 2\\
Lotus Europa & 30.4 & 4 & 95.1 & 113 & 3.77 & 1.513 & 16.90 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 2\\
Ford Pantera L & 15.8 & 8 & 351.0 & 264 & 4.22 & 3.170 & 14.50 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 4\\
Ferrari Dino & 19.7 & 6 & 145.0 & 175 & 3.62 & 2.770 & 15.50 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 6\\
\addlinespace
Maserati Bora & 15.0 & 8 & 301.0 & 335 & 3.54 & 3.570 & 14.60 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 8\\
Volvo 142E & 21.4 & 4 & 121.0 & 109 & 4.11 & 2.780 & 18.60 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}

\end{document}
```

generates this pdf:

[image]

Do you know a clean way to avoid this?

Comment: Use the needspace package and add `\Needspace{6\baselineskip}` before the table.

Comment: Add a `\clearpage` command before the table begins. Also, there doesn't seem to be any problem if you load `geometry`.

Comment: @Bernard I have the same issue with `geometry`. I don't want to use `clearpage` because it starts a new page, and my real problem deals with an automatic (Sweave) report.

Comment: And do you have the same problem if you load `ltablex` in the place of `longtable`, and use `tabularx`?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know. This code is generated by a R package, I cannot change the table environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it works here. Is it a robust solution which is supposed to work in any case ?

Comment: As the code is the same inside the table, you might  give a try changing the environment using regular expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63218/discussion-between-stephane-laurent-and-bernard).

Comment: Imho it should be robust if the value is large enough (it naturally depends on the size of your header, and don't forget the lines and the space they occupy) but you could ask @David Carlisle for confirmation.

Comment: Ok @UlrikeFischer. I have a large header in my real report, it takes four rows, and `\Needspace{24\baselineskip}` solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes it'll work well enough, the issue is probably the extra space from booktabs commands or the extra whatsits from `\rowcolor` inserting an unexpected breakpoint at the start of the table (longtable was not tested with colour or booktabs when it was written, for reasons connected with the direction of time:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no neither xcolor nor booktabs are needed to reproduce the problem (I tried). It is is really only longtable to blame ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm having trouble parsing your comment!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I meant: longtable is quite able to produce this feature on its own ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho longtable doesn't take `\LTpre` correctly into account.

You could try this patch:

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\LT@start{\vskip\LTpre}{\vskip\LTpre\endgraf}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I told @DavidCarlisle in the chat. If my analysis is correct he will hopefully correct the style.